# Is there a function for checking if I'm pressing something on any screen on Python?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have created a  code for a game called Transformice. I want to use a function which checks if I'm pressing something ('esc' for example) inside the game and finishes the program.

All functions that I read about needed me to press the letter on the console, but I want to press it while I'm playing the game and my program detects that. Is that possible (how?)?

```
from pyautogui import typewrite, locateOnScreen
from time import sleep

while(True):
    img_controle = locateOnScreen('Screenshot_1.PNG', confidence = 0.7)

    if img_controle:
        typewrite(['enter', 'up', 'up', 'enter'], interval = 0.05)
        typewrite(['enter', 'up', 'up', 'enter'], interval = 0.05)
        img_controle = None
        sleep(5)
```

Comment: If you search on the phrase "Python game detect keypress", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'esc' you could use a different key such as 'q' for quit. Then the following code could be used:

```py
import win32api as wapi

keyList = ["\b"]
for char in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 123456789,.'£$/\\":
    keyList.append(char)

def key_check():
    keys = []
    for key in keyList:
        if wapi.GetAsyncKeyState(ord(key)):
            keys.append(key)
    return keys
```

key_check() would return a list of all keys being pressed at the time the function executed.

Just periodically call this function (say on every game loop) and check with:

```py
if 'q' in key_check():
    # whatever action I want to do
```

Source code taken from: https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/master/getkeys.py